# How to get currently active UIEvent?

Tags: objective-c, uikit

**Background**

I have a custom UIWindow implementation that posts a notification in the sendEvent method. Then I have a custom view that, once added to the window hierarchy, removes itself from superview as soon as the mentioned notification is posted (i.e. tapping anywhere, in this view or not, removes the view). Finally, I have a button that causes this custom view to be added to the view hierarchy. Now the problem is that when I tap this button, the view gets added to the view hierarchy, BUT, the event that was caused by this tap reaches my custom UIWindow sendEvent method AFTER the custom view is added, thus resulting in the custom view being removed immediately after it has been added.

**Question**

I want to somehow access whatever UIEvent is currently active. Is this possible to do, and if yes, then how?

Comment: @matt Here's the related SO question that explains why I rely on sendEvent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167843/how-can-i-know-when-any-of-the-objects-on-screen-were-tapped

Comment: @matt There can be any amount, it depends on the view. My custom view is a generalized thing that does not care about what is on the screen. The only thing it cares about is to remove itself as soon as anything on the screen is tapped, and to do so without interfering with that tap.

Comment: @matt Well, if _it_ is tapped, then nothing below it will be tapped, because the tap is absorbed.

Comment: @matt I would be very happy to see such a solution (assuming that you mean that the tap will properly highlight the element that it should fall through to and so on). And it should also work with swipes etc. Basically, what I want is that whatever interaction is done, it should be detected but also forwarded seamlessly to the intended screen elements.

Comment: ©matt Yes, that is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by listening for the notification in order to track the most recent UIEvent (I provided the UIEvent in the userInfo). Then, when receiving the notification again, I made sure that it is not the same event as the one that occured just before the custom view appeared (if it is, I skip the removal of the custom view).

While this is an answer to my question, the solution to the underlaying problem that @matt proposed in an answer to the following SO question turned out to be much better: [How can I know when any of the objects on screen were tapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167843/how-can-i-know-when-any-of-the-objects-on-screen-were-tapped)